# HttpRequest not to timeout on a lengthy request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have the following Ajax call

```
function exampleAjax() {
    $('#loadingImage').show();

    var id = GetId();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Controller/MyRequest?id=" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success === true) {
                // Show Dialog Success
            }
            else {
                // Show Dialog Failure
            }
        },
        async: true,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

which calls below controller's method.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> MyRequest(string teamId)
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fullUriEndpoint)
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        else
            success = true;

        return Json(new
        {
            success = success,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = success,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Because the request takes few minutes to process (this is totally fine, server needs to do a some processing that could take up to 5 minutes or more) then the client send back an exception although the task is still executed in the backend.

Is there a way I can manage this scenario without doing a fire and forget? I want to wait for the execution of this request until it gets completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you may build a kind of polling process:

1. Client sends a request for "long operation".
2. Server starts the operation, gives it some id.
3. And immediately responds to the client that the operation has been started.
4. Then server listens for an API like GET /api/operation/:id to respond a status of given operation (done or in progress).
5. Client gets this pre-answer from (3) and run a timer, he requests the API from (4) every let's say 500ms until the operation is done or until N attempts are done.

Another option would be to provide bi-directional communication between server and client using [WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marking your answer as valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet would be to use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).  So [ignoring that you should't run long running processes on asp.net](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).. I would recommend using something that does what you need in a different and easier way.  SignalR abstracts Ajax/WebSockets so all you have to do is make calls *either way* (client to server **or** server to client).

Client to server (javascript):

```
$.connection.myHub.StartProcess()
```

Server

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
  public void StartProcess()
  {
    // DO WORK

    // Call Client!
    Clients().Client(id).ProcessFinished()
  }
}
```

Client (Javascript)

```
$.connection.myHub.ProcessFinished = function(){  
  console.log('Long process finished!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marking your answer as valid :)